# Nifi: ReplaceTextWithMapping doesnt work as expected

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I have been trying out examples in nifi and has been trying out the ReplaceTextWithMapping processor. The processor config as given below.

[image]

The mapping file is shown below.And I have used tab space between key and value.

[image]

I have followed this article [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-are-mapping-files-formatted-for-the-NiFi/td-p/102717). And there is a lots of ID in the input file to the processor.There is no error on the logs. Can someone help me understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround I could find was giving the values directly like `(ID|POS)`. This does work. But still don't know why regex is not working.